_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "bind" command: application has been destroyed in turtle py module when using mac M1
When I run any simple turtle py code on my mac it shows this image as the canvas and gives this error.
Running Mac Ventura 13.4 on M1 chip
Saw some people had a similar problem but those fixes did not work.
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rohanomalley/Desktop/turppy/firstjourney.py", line 4, in <module>
    screen = turtle.Screen()
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 3663, in Screen
    Turtle._screen = _Screen()
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 3691, in __init__
    TurtleScreen.__init__(self, _Screen._canvas)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 996, in __init__
    self.clear()
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 1028, in clear
    self.onclick(None, btn)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 1365, in onclick
    self._onscreenclick(fun, btn, add)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 669, in _onscreenclick
    self.cv.unbind("<Button-%s>" % num)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 422, in unbind
    self._canvas.unbind(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1397, in unbind
    self.tk.call('bind', self._w, sequence, '')
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "bind" command:  application has been destroyed

Here is the simple code I ran it is the same for all types of turtle code I run:
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

t.pencolor("red")

t.circle(100)

turtle.mainloop()

Here is the photo of what the canvas looks like after I run it.
Here is link the similar problem. I tried this fix and it did not work.
Link to similar problem

Can you share your code as a [mcve]? Also, please share the exact links to the people with similar problems but didn't work. That's important context. Thanks. Related: messagebox: can't invoke "bind" command: application has been destroyed

How do you expect us to help without knowing what you did (i.e. showing your code)??

@JohnGordon I added my code, sorry about that. I didn't add because it doesn't change for what type of turtle code I run.

Thanks, I appreciate it. I don't have a Mac M1 so I'll wait until someone who does comes along to reproduce and hopefully answer this.

The posted code does not have the line screen = turtle.Screen() shown in the traceback.
